# Does changing base create collisions?

Tags: probability

If I convert a decimal value into an alphanumeric, will it create collisions? The use case is this:

```
$id = base_convert(time(), 10, 36);
```

I convert the current time in seconds from base10 to base36, so alphanumeric. I know time() always produces a unique value for every second, since it always increases, but does that change when changing base? Will some results collide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will not be any collisions.
Whether we use decimal of hexadecimal or binary or alphanumeric base 36 representations for natural numbers (or roman numerals to add a weirder method), these representation method have been carefully designed to produce different representations for different integers. (In the case of roman numerals, there *may* on the other hand be different possible representations for the same number such as IIII=IV, but that is a different problem and typically each "implementation" has no such ambiguities)